# Image conversion from TImage to Blob causes image corruption

Tags: mysql, image, delphi, blob, vcl

I'm currently having an issue where I take an image that is displayed in a `TImage` component, convert it and storing it in a BLOB field. Now I know that this is not an optimized solution, but for my purposes this is fine. Not going to store huge amounts of images.

The image gets saved into a Blob field of a MySQL database. The problem comes when I want to display the image again in a `TImage` component, it only shows like half of the image, the bottem part gets corrupted in some way.

Here is the code for the insert into the DB:

```pascal
image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(fileName);
if image1.Picture.Graphic <> nil then
begin
  Field := TBlobField(database.qDBImages.FieldByName('image_one'));
  stream_one := database.qDBImages.CreateBlobStream(Field, bmWrite);
  try
    image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(stream_one);
    ShowMessage('we are saving to stream');
  finally
    database.qDBImages.Post;
    stream.Free;
  end;
```

Now the issue comes when I have to display the value back into a `TImage`, then it gets corrupted. Here is the code to display the image:

```pascal
var
  Field : TBlobField;
  Stream : TStream;
  Jpg : TJPEGImage;
begin
  database.qDBImages.Active := true;

  if database.qDBImages.Active then
  begin
    Field := TBlobField(database.qDBImages.FieldByName('image_one'));
    Stream := database.qDBImages.CreateBlobStream(Field, bmRead);
    Jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
      Jpg.LoadFromStream(Stream);
      Image1.Picture.Graphic := Jpg;
    finally
      Jpg.Free;
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

Is there any other way to convert the image to the blob field, and not get corrupted when retrieved?

I did read somewhere that it might have to to do with the length of the blob, but I'm not sure.

Is there any way to improve this?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Please show how the field is defined in the database. Did you check the size of the blob using the database management application against the BlobStream size in Delphi? This check will allow to understand if the issue is in writing the JPG to the database or reading it back.

Comment: @fpiette well in the database management application (I use myphpadmin) it just says Blob no size is shown, or any other attributes, it is just defined as a blob without size. When I run lblSize.Caption := IntToStr(database.tbBayMonitorimage.Size); I just get a 0 for the field. So do not know how to see the actual size. I did point the table to the first record before running the size function.

Comment: Are you loading actual JPGs into the `TImage`? `TPicture` allows multiple image formats, bur your re-loading code only allows JPG. You should write the image type to the Blob before the actual image data. Then you can read the image type, create the correct `TGraphic` class, and then load the data into it.

Comment: The MySQL BLOB type can store only 64 KB. Make sure you use at least MEDIUMBLOB (16 MB).

Comment: To get the size of a blob, you can use the MySQL `OCTET_LENGTH()` function.

Comment: Add the size of stream_one to be sure you have data. If size <> 0, then add an immediate reload in a TJPEGImage to see if it works.

Comment: @Olivier That did fix my problem thanks, the images I was trying to store in the field was around 2mb big. so yes this did solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was taken from the suggestion from Oliver on top. I just changed the blob field to a mediumblob field increasing the max size from 64KB to 16MB. So all thanks to Olivier